# angularjs get td by index from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am looking for a way to get value from cell with index 13. I was able to get parent element (which is `row`), but now I have problem how to get value from cell from that row.

My code - here's how I've got the row:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent().parent()
```

This is what I've got from call above:

```
[tr.jtable-data-row]
```

Cell looks like this (button inside is making the call):

```
<td><button ng-click="ChangeMEST_STA($event)" class="ng-scope">V pripravi</button></td>
```

And the angular function (empty for now):

```
      $scope.ChangeMEST_STA = function ($event) {

    cMEST_STA = "";
    cMEST_CDO2 = "";

    /* change status */
  }
```

And here is the whole row:

```
<tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" data-record-key="110002001"><td>110002001</td><td>Pločevinke</td><td>Mali kuharski mojster</td><td>15</td><td>KOS</td><td>1234567891234</td><td>MK27Q3 (V4FSPY)</td><td>VjRGU1BZIE1L</td><td><input type="checkbox" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"></td><td><input type="text" title="Vnesi količino" style="width: 30px" value="1"></td><td><i id="tdAddToCart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart ng-scope" style="font-size: 20px; color: black; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="AddToDeliveryList()"></i></td><td style="display: none;"><input type="text" style="width:200px; display:none;" value="110000021"></td><td style="display: none;">1</td><td><button ng-click="ChangeMEST_STA($event)" class="ng-scope">V pripravi</button></td></tr>
```

How to use that call to get value from cell? I don't know how to combine HTML with angularjs. I would like to use something like: `td:nth-child(12)`

Comment: could you add the area of the html template to see how your iterating over the data.

Comment: `$(event.currentTarget).closest('tr.jtable-data-row:nth-of-type(12)')` ? or `$(event.currentTarget).closest('tr').eq(12);`

Comment: Is it also possible to set value in that cell? One of the cells has button on which I would like to change text.

Comment: @ntgCleaner - this is not working, I've got empty object.

Comment: @FrenkyB Could you please include the HTML code so we know what you're working with?

Comment: @TomNijs - I've added HTML for row and cell. Do I need to paste anything more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find your TD, use:

```
$(".jtable-data-row.jtable-row-even").find("td")[12];
```

To set the value of it, use:

```
$($(".jtable-data-row.jtable-row-even").find("td")[12]).text(222222);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see your HTML now.

Try this:

HTML

```
<tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" data-record-key="110002001">
    <td>110002001</td>
    <td>Pločevinke</td>
    <td>Mali kuharski mojster</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>KOS</td>
    <td>1234567891234</td>
    <td>MK27Q3 (V4FSPY)</td>
    <td>VjRGU1BZIE1L</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"></td>
    <td><input type="text" title="Vnesi količino" style="width: 30px" value="1"></td>
    <td><i id="tdAddToCart" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart ng-scope" style="font-size: 20px; color: black; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="AddToDeliveryList()"></i></td>
    <td style="display: none;"><input type="text" style="width:200px; display:none;" value="110000021"></td>
    <td style="display: none;">1</td>
    <td><button ng-click="ChangeMEST_STA($event)" class="ng-scope">V pripravi</button></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript

```
$(event.currentTarget).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(13)').text();
```